# Возможно ли остановить PHP без перезагрузки сервера?

Tags: рекурсия, php

Есть некий код:

script_a.php

```
<?php
// некое действие
$f = fopen('test.txt', 'a');
fwrite($f, date('h:i:s') . PHP_EOL);
fclose($f);

sleep(1);
$k = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/script_b.php');
//echo $k;
die();
?>
```

и script_b.php

```
<?php
// некое действие
$f = fopen('test.txt', 'a');
fwrite($f, date('h:i:s') . PHP_EOL);
fclose($f);

sleep(1);
$k = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/script_a.php');
//echo $k;
die();
?>
```

Без шуток, это «чудо» работает бесконечно, доступа к серваку нет, возможно ли каким то образом остановить «это»

Comment: вообще нет доступа? даже фтп?

Comment: только фтп и есть, но я привёл «лёгкую» версию кода, по факту там создается рандомное имя файла типа "hd7yH6enn" и запускается, в котором удаляется прошлый (а иногда не удаляется) и так по кругу, скрипты конечно же я удалил, но на вид вся деятельность процесса. Это всё в корневой папке которую не удалишь.

Comment: если все в одной папке происходит - можно попробовать папку заблокировать на запись. может выпадет в ошибку и прекратится. И еще как вариант добавить htaccess с убиванием PHP файла как исполняемого. Потом вернуть назад, когда процессы умрут.

Comment: это корень к сожалению, и выставить права на "корень" через фтп менеждер (total commander) мне не даёт

Comment: ощущение что вы пишете "нехороший" скрипт для зависания сервера :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

попробуйте в корень добавить htaccess с

```
RemoveHandler .php 
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .php
```

но учтите, что все PHP скрипты начнут отдаваться как текстовики в исходном коде.

Comment: Спасибо, прописал, но всё равно выполняется и PHP и вся эта ерунда.

Comment: не за что. не забудьте удалить эти строки. ))))